# Yoast post_tag-sitemap giving error 500

Tags: wordpress, plugins, sitemap

I have a wordpress site with Yoast SEO plugin. The plugin generate's my sitemap_index.xml but i cant access some of them.

I can access my post-sitemap.xml and category-sitemap.xml.
But i can't access my tags XML (post_tag-sitemap.xml). It gives error 500.

This is my eeror log:

---

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in
>   /home/******/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/inc/class-sitemaps.php on line 439

---

I already tried to change the define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M'); in my wp-config.php with no success.
I already tried to decrease the number of items in Yoast Sitemap plugin with no success.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution woked perfectly with me couple of times:

`if (!defined('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT'))
    define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT','128M');`

If still facing the problem add this line to wp-config.php:

`define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');`

If the kept appearing create php.ini file in your site root (usually www, public_html or htdocs folder) and add the following line:

`memory_limit = 64MB`

Goodluck.

Source [WPAPI](http://wpapi.com/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/wordpressapi.com//solved-for-wordpress-old-and-new-versions-php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-33554432-bytes-exhausted/_index.html.old)